# SOLID и RxJava архитектура приложения

Tags: java, android

Предположим что разрабатывается приложение.
Выбран паттерн MVP. 
И необходимо придерживаться SOLID принципов.

Например, создали класс репозиторий, методы репозитория обвернуты в observable от rxJava.
Используем этот репозиторий в презентере.
Как в этом случае работает dependency inversion principle?
Получается, необходимо для репозитория сделать интерфейс, с описанием методов которые возвращают observable? - вроде, где-то читал что вообще по правильному не должны зависит от каких то сторонних фреймворков, а где-то читал что нужно считать rx как стандартную библиотеку и не париться по этому поводу.

Насколько это правильно? Можете привести какой нибудь пример с реального проекта с rx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, все верно нужно создать интерфейс репозитория. Инжектим этот интерфейс в презентер. Тогда наш презентер не будет зависеть от реализации репозитория, а будет зависеть от абстракции. Это помогает в тех случаях, когда нам нужно поменять класс репозитория на другой класс совсем с другой логикой. Например, сначала у нас был репозиторий с тестовыми данными, потом бекенд закончил делать апи и мы подменили репозиторий на реальный, так как интерфейс репозитория остался такой же, то код презентера мы не меняем.

Наверное, вы читали в статьях о clean architecture, что проект не должен зависеть от каких-то фреймфорков. Это правда и RxJava во всех слоях приложения это нарушение этого принципа. Но правда и то, что в андроиде сейчас RxJava это стандарт (как Stream API в java) поэтому она есть во всем проекте.

Примеров в интернете очень много, один из фундаментальных это вот [этот](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture). Там как раз то, что я описал выше есть. На хабре есть [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/250659/) по этому репозиторию, чтобы лечге понимать, что происходит в коде.

Еще есть такая [статья](https://habr.com/ru/company/mobileup/blog/335382/) для большего понимания